# Remove recursively, but exclude a tree of particular directories

Tags: python, bash

Let's say that I have a directory named "sample" 
and it contains the next content

```
sample
├── files
│   └── usr
│       ├── 1.txt
│       ├── 2.txt
│       └── bin
│           └── 12.txt
├── opt
│   └── lib
│       ├── 33.txt
│       └── log
│           └── access.log
├── sub_dir1
│   └── sub_dir1.1
│       └── sub_dir1.1.1
└── sub_dir2
    └── sub_dir2.2
        └── sub_dir2.2.2
```

How can I remove everything exclude `sample/opt/lib/log/access.log`

I hoped something like that would work

```
find sample/ -type d -print  | grep -v "sample/opt/lib/log/access.log" | xargs rm -rf
```

but it doesn't

Comment: Do you also want to delete directories (presumably except `sample`, `sample/opt`, `sample/opt/lib`, and `sample/opt/lib/log`)?

Comment: `find sample/ ! -path 'sample/opt/lib/log/access.log'  delete` will work fine but may report some warning about `Directory not empty` that you may ignore by using `2>/dev/null` in front of that `find` command.

Comment: @GordonDavisson yes.

Comment: @anubhava ohh, my bad, i didn't check that despite of  error content was removed successfully . thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `gnu find` command should work for you:

```
find sample/ ! -path 'sample/opt/lib/log/access.log' -delete 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Python: you can remove all the files except the "access.log" then remove the folders:

```py
for root, folders, files in os.walk(sample_dir):
    for name in files:
        if name != "access.log":
            os.remove(os.path.join(root, name))

for root, folders, files in os.walk(sample_dir, topdown=False):
    try:
        os.rmdir(root)
    except IOError:
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason the grep -v is not properly matching is that `find sample/` will return all matches as `sample//some/path` which is ok as far as bash is concerned.

So to make your code work as desired in a one-liner shell script you can do any of the following.

- `find sample -type d -print | grep -v "sample/opt/lib/log/access.log" | xargs rm -rf`
- `find sample/ -type d -print | grep -v "sample//opt/lib/log/access.log" | xargs rm -rf`

But a word for the wise... it is possible that a typographical error could find you remove more than you intended. It would be recommended to always have a positive check prior to the xargs rm such as `| grep sample | xargs rm -rf`